# How do I create a constant in services.js that the User has chosen in an ionic app (or basically any angularJS) app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

**Updated Post**
So after much playing around I've come up with this:
my Services.js has no value or constant, instead I have something like this:

```
.factory('urlFactory', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return {
        getUrl: function(baseURL) {
            $resource(baseURL + "helloWorld/");
        }
    }
}])
```

And in my app.js in a .state I have:

```
resolve: {
    building: ['$stateParams', 'urlFactory', function($stateParams, urlFactory) {
        var helloWorld = urlFactory.getUrl($scope.baseURL).get({
            id: parseInt($stateParams.id, 10)
        });
        return helloWorld;
    }]
}
```

And finally in my controller.js I have:

```
$scope.setURL = function() {
    console.log('Set BaseURL ' + $scope.baseURL.url);
    $localStorage.storeObject('baseURL', $scope.baseURL);
    $scope.baseURL = $scope.baseURL.url;
    $scope.closeDomainModal();
};
```

However, it doesn't work, could anyone help me figure out why. Thanks.

**Origianl Post**
I normally have a constant defined in my `services.js` like so:

```
.constant("baseURL","http://localhost:3000/").
```

and each of the factories in the `services.js` returns a `$resource` url using this baseURL. However, at the start of the app, the user enters the url that'll be used for as the baseURL. The problem is, how do I get the URL that the user has selected as the constant baseURL that can be used in the services. 
Or is there a better, more proper way of going about this?

I've tried to use `$scope` in the services but it doesn't work. Is there another way of using a global variable here?
Also, when the user enters the URL, it's stored in local memory. So is it possible that I can read this using `$localStorage`?
I've tried using `$localStorage` to set the constant in the services, but to no avail.

Or is there a way where I can pass the value of the user-defined baseURL as a parameter to the factory method?
MANY THANKS.

Answer (score 1):

You could possible use `.value` instead of `.constant`. It's close to the same as `.constant` but you could can change the value once the app is running, e.g. when the user enters their value.

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .value('baseURL', 'default')
    .controller('Controller', ['$scope', 'baseURL',
        function($scope, baseURL) {

            // use this to let the user update the url
            $scope.updateURL = function(url) {
                baseURL = url;
            };
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've tried it as: .value("baseURL", baseURL), in the sercvices.js,  but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you have something like this: `app.constant('baseURL', 'url').value('baseURL', baseURL)`?

Comment: No , just .value("baseURL", baseURL). So Basically: angular.module('app.services', ['ngResource'])   .value("baseURL", baseURL)         Get a Error: baseURL is not defined

Comment: Yeah that will happen because the baseURL that you're try to set is not defined. You probably want to set it as a string. `.value('baseURL', 'defaultURL')`

Comment: Thanks again for the comment and the code. However, it didn't work for me for some reason. So in the Services.js I have the .value(baseURL, default), and in the app.js, I have: baseURL = updatedURL. But unfortunately it still calls the defaultURL when I call the factory methods in the services.js

Comment: Is there any way I can use $localStorage.getObject('baseURL', '{}'); in the Services.js

Comment: Would you mind creating a simple plnkr version of what you have? I could help better if I had that to look at. Maybe update your question with the link to it